# a very basic question on finding the discriminant for $x^2+2(a-3)x-3a-7=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Sorry for asking such a basic question.

In the following quadratic equation

$$x^2+2(a-3)x-3a-7=0$$

by my calculations,

$$D=\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2-ac=(a-3)^2-1(-3a-7)=a^2-6a+9+3a+7=a^2-3a+16$$

But in a PDF article that describes a solution to a problem concerning this equation the discriminant is calculated as

$$a^2-3a+2$$

Is there any error in my calculation?

Comment: Your calculation seems correct - must be a typo somewhere.

Comment: @DietrichBurde - thanks! Could be that. I change my books but keep finding typos. Must be a good sign. (0:

Comment: @CopperKettle. Your result is correct. One more typo in a book !

Comment: change $-7$ for $+7$ and see what happens...

Comment: @Math-fun - indeed! Thank you. I've notified the author of the article (which is a great guide on quadratics in all respects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice, compare the given equation: $x^2+2(a-3)x-3a-7=0$ with $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$, we get $$A=1, \ B=2(a-3), \ C=-3a-7$$

Hence,

discriminant is calculated as follows $$D=B^2-4AC=\left(2(a-3)\right)^2-4(1)(-(3a+7))$$ $$=4a^2-24a+36+12a+28$$ $$=4a^2-12a+64$$

Comment: OK, so $D=4(a^2-3a+16)$, which is what the OP did.

Comment: Oh, yes you are right. Thanks

Comment: Which is the OP result !